# Get all the record matching the condition Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle12c

I have the below table structure and wanted to get all the records after the row which matches the given condition

```
FltNbr   Date   Stat_Ind
=======  =====  =========
1         15-MAR  0
2         16-MAR  1
3         17-MAR  0
4         18-MAR  1
5         19-MAR  0
6         19-MAR  0
```

I want to get all the records after the row whose Stat_ind =1, in this case the FltNbr 4 has the last occurrence of 1 and want to retrieve all the records after the FltNbr

So the result should be -

```
FltNbr   Date   Stat_Ind
=======  =====  =========
5         19-MAR  0
6         19-MAR  0
```

Please help with the SQL

Answer (score 0):

It is unclear if by "previous" you mean by `date`, `fltnbr` or both.  The following assumes that you mean `fltnbr`.

Use `lag()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             lag(stat_ind) over (order by fltnbr) as prev_stat_ind
      from t
     ) t
where prev_stat_ind = 1;
```

EDIT:

If you want the rows *after* the last "1", then:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.fltnbr > all (select t2.fltnbr from t t2 where t2.stat_ind = 1);
```

Note that this uses `> all`.  This handles the case where there are no rows with a status of `1`.  You can also use:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.fltnbr > (select coalesce(max(t2.fltnbr, t.fltnbr - 1)
                  from t t2
                  where t2.stat_ind = 1
                 );
```

Comment: Hi, I want to get the last matching row whose stat_ind is 1, then all the rows after that record in the table. WIth the above query I am getting all the rows, even if you order by flt_nbr it won't work as the flt_nbr is not oredered set